# Swift 2 error handling of audio recording code

Tags: xcode

can someone please assist me? I have some code (which I know runs properly in Xcode 6) that is having difficulty executing in Xcode 7 (due to the changes in error handling for Swift 2). I tried to convert the code using the latest Swift syntax in Xcode 7, but no recommendations were offered. Any suggestions?

```
    //Setup audio session
    var session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord,error: nil)

    //Initialize and prepare the recorder
    audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL: filePath, settings: nil, error:nil)
    audioRecorder.meteringEnabled = true;
    audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()
    audioRecorder.record()

}

@IBAction func stopAudio(sender: UIButton) {
    recordingInProgress.hidden = true
    //TODO: Stop recording the user's voice
    audioRecorder.stop()
    var audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance();
    audioSession.setActive(false, error:nil)

}
```

The Error messages are for the following code:

session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord,error: nil)

**Extra argument 'error' in call**

audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL: filePath, settings: nil, error:nil)

**Cannot find an initializer for type 'AVAudioRecorder' that accepts an argument list of type '(URL: NSURL?, settings: nil, error: nil)'**

audioSession.setActive(false, error:nil)

****Extra argument 'error' in call****

Comment: You say it doesn't work properly, but what are the symptoms, and what do you expect proper execution to be?

Comment: Quickfix: change `audioSession.setActive(false, error:nil)` to `try! audioSession.setActive(false)` (note that this triggers a runtime assertion when there's an error!). Long-term fix: Learn how error handling works ;) (the WWDC Session videos are great!). You can also use the migrator (Edit -> Refactor -> Migrate to latest Swift syntax).

Answer (score 0):

try this class ive tested this and it works in the latest version of swift and Xcode

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class RecordViewController: UIViewController {

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    var baseString : String = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! String
    var pathComponents = [baseString, NSUUID().UUIDString + ".m4a"]
    self.audioURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPathComponents(pathComponents)!

        var session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, error:  nil)

        var recordSettings: [NSObject : AnyObject] = Dictionary()
        recordSettings[AVFormatIDKey] = kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC
        recordSettings[AVSampleRateKey] = 44100.0
        recordSettings[AVNumberOfChannelsKey] = 2

        self.audioRecorder = AVAudioRecorder(URL: self.audioURL, settings:    recordSettings, error: nil)
    self.audioRecorder.meteringEnabled = true
    self.audioRecorder.prepareToRecord()

        // Super init is below
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
```

you will then have to implement your buttons of course

something like this

```
@IBAction func recordPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

     if self.audioRecorder.recording {
        self.audioRecorder.stop()
        self.recordButton.setTitle("RECORD", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        self.playButton.enabled = true

    } else {

        var session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        session.setActive(true, error: nil)
        self.audioRecorder.record()
        self.recordButton.setTitle("PLAY", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        self.playButton.enabled = false
    }


}


@IBAction func playPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: self.audioURL, error: nil)
    audioPlayer.play()

    }


}
```